# Face box like plugin - All faces not showing on webpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I have put on the facebook iframe code for Like box with showfaces set to true. When i generate the code from http://developers.facebook.com it shows all faces there, but when i embed it in my webpage, it shows only two faces. I tried XFBML version of code too, but has same results.
The fanbox can be seen [here](http://tinyurl.com/6wn3pfk)
[image: This image here shows the problem]

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause. Faces of only those fans will be visible, who have made their likes and dislikes public in their facebook privacy settings. So its basically the privacy settings issue not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this code. It's working fine for me.

```
 <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FYOUR-USER-NAM-HERE&amp;width&amp;height=290&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true&amp;header=true&amp;stream=false&amp;show_border=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; height:290px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```